# Acumatica: Error on MoveNext from Stock Inventory GI

Tags: c#, acumatica

I am moving a customer from Acumatica Build 21.118.0038 to Build 21.218.0027.

I have a customization package that needs updated. When I go into the customized Generic Inquiry, I get a list of Stock Items:

[image: Generic Inquiry]

But selecting any of them generates an error:

[image: Error]

I have two questions. One, is of course how to fix this. But the bigger question is:
**"How do I go about debugging this???"**

I run Visual Studio, and attach it to the Web Session, but the error is not thrown from within the code. So no break happens.

In my customization package, I have an initalize override:

```
   public class InventoryItemMaint_Extension : PXGraphExtension<InventoryItemMaint>
    {
        static string INVENTORYITEMINQUOTESreport = "(C) Inventory Items in Quotes";
        public override void Initialize()
        {
            base.Initialize();
            this.Report.AddMenuAction(InventoryItemSalesOrders);
            this.Inquiry.AddMenuAction(OpenQuotesCode);
        }
```

And if I set a breakpoint it *does* get hit. But from there, I get nothing in the Studio. Just the error in the browser. The trace log is no help to me.

There is no MoveNext Error in the log:
[image: Log]

So, where do I go to find out what is causing this issue?

[EDIT]
FIRST I believe the error happens in thge screen the GI loads (ie IN202500) even tho the Trace is showing the error raised in the GI.

I am seeing this error in IN202500:
Redirect0:/IPS21R1/(W(2))/pages/in/in202500.aspx@DO NOT USE

That seems like maybe something was being used is now Deprecated? IDK. @Do NOT USE seems declarative.

2/3/2023 2:08:09 PM Information:
Redirect0:/IPS21R1/(W(2))/pages/in/in202500.aspx@DO NOT USE

at PX.Web.UI.PXBaseDataSource.ExecuteSelect(String viewName, DataSourceSelectArguments arguments, PXDSSelectArguments pxarguments)
at PX.Web.UI.PXDataSource.ExecuteSelect(String viewName, DataSourceSelectArguments arguments, PXDSSelectArguments pxarguments)
at PX.Web.UI.PXDataSourceView.Select(DataSourceSelectArguments arguments, PXDSSelectArguments swarguments, DataSourceViewSelectCallback callback)
at PX.Web.UI.PXFormDataProvider.DataBind()
at PX.Web.UI.PXCallbackManager.CollectDataControls(Dictionary`2 controlsDic, List`1 controlsList)
at PX.Web.UI.PXCallbackManager.RenderClientData(PXCallbackResultMethod resultMethod, XmlWriter writer)
at PX.Web.UI.PXCallbackManager.GetCallbackResultInternal(PXCallbackResultMethod resultMethod)

[MORE EDITS]

Following Samvel Petrosov's suggestion, I turned on logging, but I really don't know what I am looking for.

This is what I turned on:

[image: Profiler]

Looking at what it returns I can get the SQL it is running. I put that in the SQL Server Management and it runs fine, I get one record back, which is what I would expect. There are 7 variables that come back null, and five of them are user defined columns, but all of them are either strings, or declared as nullable. So I am at a loss as to why this is failing. :

I suspect this MIGHT have something to do with Workflow, only because I believe that had changes made to is between 21.118 and 21.218 -- But I don't know where to begin to look for the offending object.

Can anyone give any suggestions as to where to start with this?

Comment: Have you tried to turn on the Request Profiler and check the logs there? It usually captures this kind of issue. Most likely the error happens in some field/row selecting/selecting/verifying event handler. Based on your screenshot it looks like the IN202500 page actually opens but shows the error message, so the stack trace opened from that page should also contains some information

Comment: @SamvelPetrosov I'm afraid I don't know what you are referring to with: Request Profiler. Where is that enabled?

Comment: You can access it from the System Management-> System Health Diagnostics-> Request Profiler https://ibb.co/pXLjmcf and turn on the logging there and check the logs https://ibb.co/sRW5FnD . Make sure to turn it off after completing the checking as it creates a lot of loading on the system.

Comment: @SamvelPetrosov -- I made changes to the question showing the Profiler settings. I still don't have any idea where the issue is tho. Can you look at my edits and comment?